# Cannot grant roles to users

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table EMPLOYEES that I wish to grant access to for a role called MANAGER. This role will be granted to a user called judy. The code to set this up is as follows

(Logged in as system)

```
SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

Session altered.

SQL> create user judy identified by bob;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to judy;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create role manager;

Role created.

SQL> grant select on employees to manager;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter role manager identified by manager_password;

Role altered.

SQL> grant manager to judy;

Grant succeeded.
```

However, when I log in as judy, I am unable to select from the EMPLOYEES table as a MANAGER:

(Logged in as Judy)

```
SQL> select * from system.employees;
select * from system.employees
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Why can't judy access the employees table?

EDIT:

While logged in as judy, issuing the following command fixes the issue:

```
set role manager identified by manager_password;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enable the role in Judy's session with

```
SET ROLE manager
         IDENTIFIED BY manager_password;
```

prior accessing `system.employees`.

Or set the role `manager` as Judy's default role after granting it.

```
ALTER USER judy
           DEFAULT ROLE manager;
```

or maybe

```
ALTER USER judy
           DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
```

to make all roles granted to Judy default.

Answer (score 1):

Try to grant `resource` also :

```
SQL> grant resource to judy;
```

P.S. do not use `system` user for testing, and even for productional purposes, but only for management.

Comment: granting resource to judy results in the same error.